# Use "and" and "or" in a single sentence to enable three options. Please parse

Tags: coordinating-conjunctions, logic

So I am trying to parse the following sentence structure:

> X must provide A and B or C.

No commas are present and two coordinating conjunctions are present with no hints as to how to parse. I have substituted the nouns with variables to protect the innocent from easy googling.

Anyway, my colleagues and I (scientists) are trying to decide if the author intend (A + B) or C as opposed to A + (B or C). Are there PEMDAS-type rules for coordinating conjunctions?

I know the above structure is probably grammatically incorrect, but need to interpret meaning in spite of this. I am assuming the author intended this to follow standard logical operations so "and" should be applied before the "or" so I am leaning toward: (A + B) or C.

Am I correct? Does grammar follow logical operations?

Comment: Do you follow PEMDAS-like rules when writing with coordinating conjunctions? If you don't, why would you assume that other authors do?

Answer (score 1):

Not reliably. English is full of ambiguity with things like this, and it leads to jokes.

> Clerk: Do you want fries, or onion rings?

> Engineer: Yes.

or

> "Let's eat grandma: how commas save lives."

I can't find online examples of this, because it's too confusing and we usually just do a better job (using commas, or other words like "either"). I also lean toward it being `(A and B) or C`, but this may be because I'm a technical type too.

Answer (score -1):

There is no definitive answer based on what you have provided. From a grammatical standpoint it truly could go either way.

In this situation I would rely on context clues to try to figure it out, but as you have replaced the nouns with variables that is not possible (it may be that it was not possible even with the nouns intact).

Personally, I would lean towards A + (B or C) but there is really no objective reason for that.